# bsValueChange not triggering event if user changes date manually

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have this in my angular component html.

```
<div class='col-md-2 pr-1'>
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control date-input" placeholder="Leaving Date To (DD/MM/YYYY)"
    formControlName="leaveDateTo" bsDatepicker #dp4="bsDatepicker" [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY', showWeekNumbers:
    false }" (bsValueChange)="onLeaveDateChange()"
    [minDate]="filterForm.get('dateFrom') != null ? this.filterForm.get('dateFrom').value : null" windowScroll
    (windowScroll)="onScrollEvent()" />
</div>
```

This is the code in the component ts file.

```
onLeaveDateChange() {
  let dateFromValue = this.filterForm.get('leaveDateFrom').value;
  let dateToValue = this.filterForm.get('leaveDateTo').value;
  if ((dateFromValue) && (dateToValue)) {
    if (dateFromValue > dateToValue) {
      this.filterForm.get('leaveDateTo').reset();
    }
    else {
      this.applyFiltersEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

If I select a date from the datepicker as a datepicker the onLeaveChange function is called as expected.  However, if I manually delete the value using the keyboard not only is the function not called, but the control continues to retain the value:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to trigger the function if the user changes the date using the keyboard rather than the datepicker control?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be three-fold.  First, I had to replace

```
(bsValueChange)="onLeaveDateChange()"
```

with

```
(ngModelChange)="onLeaveDateChange()"
```

Second, I had to understand that, in using keyboard input, the change event didn't fire until the user tabbed off the control.

Third, there was a bug in the logic of my onLeaveDateChange function.